# jQuery .show() makes input box shiver

Tags: jquery

My code:

```
$('input').hide().show(10000);
```

I have tested [the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pzP4Q/) with Google Chrome 14 on Windows 7 and Mac OS 10.7.

The input box shivers towards the end of the animation. Is this a bug or the expected effect?

Comment: Interesting. Can reproduce on Chrome 14 on OS X. Does not happen in Safari 5 or Firefox 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a bug I think. The truth is that the browser is usually unable to set **non-integer** `width` or `height` of an input element, trying to round, for example, `height: 11.007252845381956px` to `height: 11px` or `12px`.

The shivering disappears once you set `vertical-align` as follows ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lapple/pzP4Q/5/)):

```
input {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Therefore I can assume that the vibration comes from browser's inability to determine (or round) `height`, `line-height` or any other property that influences the vertical alignment.

Comment: That still qualifies as a browser bug, but what you've provided is a good explanation.

Comment: @Lapple: How do you explain that only part of the animation shivers?

Comment: @GregPettit: Do you think this bug is worth reporting to the jQuery team?

Comment: jQuery animation uses an easing, called 'swing'. The animation goes slower at the beginning, then accelerates to a faster and constant speed, and slows down just before the end. This pattern of movement is considered to reflect the way motion prevails in nature.

Comment: Hence, during the middle stage, the rate of expansion doesn't allow browser to calculate height or offset and redraw the 'input' element accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably browser's bug. It "vibrates" with 1000 duration too so I assume it's browser-related bug

http://jsfiddle.net/pzP4Q/1/